# SQLite Error 1: 'near ")": syntax error'.'

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm making a project for school, but I'm stuck on this syntax error in SQL (I'm using SQLite).

The goal of this line is to create an empty table with a `Sandwich_ID`, `Bread_ID` and a `Sandwich_price` column. The `Sandwich_ID` is the primary key, and the `Bread_ID` is specified in the `Bread` table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sandwiches 
(
     Sandwich_ID INT, 
     Bread_ID INT, 
     Sandwich_price FLOAT, 
     PRIMARY KEY (Sandwich_ID), 
     FOREIGN KEY (Bread_ID)
);
```

Error message:

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'near ")": syntax error'.'

I also tried decimal instead of float but still have the error.

EDIT: Now I'm using a reference

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Breads 
(
    Bread_ID INT, 
    Bread_name VARCHAR(40), 
    Bread_price FLOAT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Bread_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sandwiches 
(
    Sandwich_ID INT, 
    Bread_ID INT, 
    Sandwich_price FLOAT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Sandwich_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Bread_ID) REFERENCES Breads(Bread_ID)
);
```

I still have a syntax error.

Comment: A foreign key has to refer to something, so the definition is incomplete.  You should also be using `decimal`/`numeric` for prices.

Comment: `sql` is a language. `Create table if not exist` is product specific. What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLite

Comment: I tried to change float to decimal, but i still have the error

Answer (score 2):

A foreign key needs to point to something. E.g., here it seems as though you should have a "breads" table or something of the sorts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sandwiches (
    Sandwich_ID int,
    Bread_ID int, 
    Sandwich_price float, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Sandwich_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Bread_ID) REFERENCES Breads(Bread_IS)
    -- Here ---------------^
)
```

Comment: I still get a syntax error `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Breads 
(
    Bread_ID INT, 
    Bread_name VARCHAR(40), 
    Bread_price FLOAT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Bread_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sandwiches 
(
    Sandwich_ID INT, 
    Bread_ID INT, 
    Sandwich_price FLOAT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Sandwich_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Bread_ID) REFERENCES Breads(Bread_ID)
);`